# Why is novelty mandatory for a Ph.D. degree?

Tags: phd, research-topic, publishability

The institute I am studying at has added the following requirement recently:

> A PhD scholar must publish two papers in his/her corresponding field
>   in SCI journals.

This means that a student cannot get PhD without two SCI rated papers. To the best of my knowledge, novelty is a mandate for such journals; hence, novelty has became mandatory for a student to get PhD in my institute.

In this context, I have the following query: **Why is novelty mandatory for a PhD degree?**

Consider a scenario in which a student is ambitious and wants to do research on an open problem or famous unsolved problem in his/her field. The student cannot attempt to research such a topic since research may be locally saturated, and he/she cannot come up with a novel idea. Does the rule not restrict the research on such problems? I can see the alternatives like tutorial papers, survey papers, etc., but some of these require only highly experienced geeks.

**Note**: Assume that neither the PhD student nor the PhD supervisor is an extraordinary person in that particular field.

Comment: Before the requirement about two papers in SCI journals, did your institute award Ph.D.degrees without any requirement of novelty? In my opinion, that would be very strange and not consistent with what a Ph.D. should mean.

Comment: Before that, there is no such explicit rule and solely depends on mentor and doctoral review committee and any papers got priority I.e., not only SCI papers.

Comment: I don’t understand the last paragraph of your question. Why should a requirement for novelty be a problem for ambitious students?

Comment: Suppose a person selects Riemann hypothesis as his PhD topic. The research is happening on it all over the mathematics community and it is very rare that a PhD student can contribute to it. @Thomas

Comment: No sane advisor would allow a student to base his thesis 100% on proving the Riemann hypothesis. If the student insists and somehow manages to convince the advisor to do so, then he should consider the option that **nothing** will come out of it – this was his own choice to start with, so he should accept the consequences. If the rules state that two papers with novel results are a requirement, one needs to have results. Negative results are also results, and often very important, but "I've done research for 4 years but absolutely nothing worked; give me a PhD" is not enough.

Comment: That's my point: Then the research what the student is doing is mostly for publishing the SCI papers. @corey979

Comment: @hanugm that's a side effect - if the student is doing good work then she will end up publishing SCI papers. The motivation you describe is vague and hard to pin down as well, e.g. is the student doing research so she can be awarded a PhD?

Comment: One of the first lessons of PhD studies is that you’re likely not as smart as you think and that you’re likely to fail if working on famous unsolved problems.

Comment: @Thomas: "Why should a requirement for novelty be a problem for ambitious students?" - if I interpret the question correctly: Even the most ambitious student has zero influence on whether there still *is* anything novel to discover. Thus, in a (globally, far; for individual subfields maybe not so far at all) future, once all relevant knowledge has been discovered, no more PhD degrees can be granted even to the most brilliant of people. This is a fundamental difference to e.g. Bachelor degrees, which are typically meant to certify professional skills and can keep being granted forever.

Comment: See *illustrated guide to a PhD*: http://matt.might.net/articles/phd-school-in-pictures/

Comment: Novelty does not require being an extraordinary person in your field.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper _Even the most ambitious student has zero influence on whether there still is anything novel to discover._ — This is true, but vacuously so.  There is **always** more to discover!

Comment: Consider one to say "Make me a discoverer of things", and the reply should be "Discover something, and we'll talk."

Comment: Novelty or originality is already a requirement of PhD courses, even those without a publishing requirement. The work is expected to of publishable quality, whether or not is has been yet. Examiners will assess your thesis based on this and other criteria that you can find publicly available. They should conform to international standards. This does not have to be radically novel, a new approach to an existing problem or a new application of an existing technique is acceptable (even if it is then scooped). Any advisor should be able to support this.

Answer (score 73):

Novelty is a basic requirement in research because without novel results, the work is of at best limited usefulness. It's not useless - review papers are useful - but it's less interesting to the people at the frontier. In the case of a PhD, it is supposed to signify a student is now capable of doing research. Research (as opposed to literature review) necessarily involves new and novel results. Therefore novelty is a requirement.

If I understand your last paragraph right, you're wondering about open problems which might be too complex to solve in one go. But in that case, you still get new and novel results - they might be partial results, but they're still results. The same goes for research using new methods that turn out not to work: knowing where not to look is not as useful as knowing where to look, but by narrowing the parameter space, it's still useful.

Comment: * But in that case, you still get new and novel results*... but it is very rare that a PhD student with a normal supervisor can get such results.

Comment: @hanugm certainly not, most PhD students get such results. How else did your predecessors at your institution get awarded PhDs? They discovered enough new things to publish two SCI-indexed papers. See also corey979's comment.

Comment: @hanugm at my institution every single PhD student has new and novel results. The importance of the results vary, with some having papers at Nature/Science and others publishing at very insignificant local journals, but they always have results. That's what you do in your PhD. You do stuff no one did before. Whether someone cares about it is another thing, but it's still new.

Comment: @Gimelist in that case, the importance of novelty may be less also...

Comment: @hanugm That may be true, but the single most important criterion for awarding a PhD is whether the student was able to obtain (publishable) original results. The importance of these results will be the largest factor in determining the grade of the PhD. Writing an excellent review of the literature is usually not enough for a PhD, although it is a popular format for Master's theses.

Comment: Also note that there *are* doctoral degrees that do not require original research, or at least not anything close to the levels of originality and substantiality required for a PhD. Examples include the DA (Doctor of Arts) degree, as well as many professional degrees such as MD, JD, PharmD, and DDS. A *Ph*D is a *research* doctorate.

Comment: To improve this answer: "novelty" suggests it has to be a new concept. It might be better phrased as "new information". An essential part of science is reproducing and testing concepts from other teams. This is not creating a novel idea yourself; but documenting whether the new concept also works for you or not, and the ways your results differ from the original team's, is essential for good science. And that's absolutely PhD paper material because it's new information, even if it isn't novel.

Answer (score 37):

This answer will be a bit different and not limited to the sciences as the other current answers seem to be. It will also apply to many similar degrees not designated PhD. I'll use the term "doctorate" as an abbreviation for "research doctorate" to distinguish it from other degrees such as those that are clinically focused, for example.

Study for a doctorate (PhD and similar degrees) in a field is intended to teach you how to carry out *scholarship* in that field, whatever it is. Scholarship is always intended to be the *extension of knowledge*. A successful scholar extends what is known in the field of interest. In literature, for example, you can study *Dr. Faustus* by Goethe and give a perspective never considered before. This would be, as are many (most?) studies, very narrow. But it can also be very deep. If someone says that your thoughts aren't actually novel, but a simple extension of things written a few (or a lot of) years ago, then those thoughts don't really *extend knowledge*. So, if all you can accomplish are *derivative* works, without novelty, then you haven't reached the point of being able to *extend knowledge* in your field.

The actual accomplishment need not be earth shattering in its implications. Most are not - even in mathematics and the sciences. But you have to be able to say something that is *interesting* to other scholars, preferably something that will permit them to extend their own work in new ways not yet considered.

There are a lot of ways to demonstrate that you are, indeed, able to extend knowledge in your field. A requirement of publication in a good journal is just one way and it is easy for the faculty to judge, since the reviewers and editors of the journal help them in their judgement task. Not so many years ago, in mathematics, there was no requirement to publish before obtaining the doctorate and your "proof of ability" was measured only in your dissertation as evaluated by the local faculty, perhaps with some supplementing.

Research in any field is directed at extending the "known world". You need to demonstrate the ability to do that to earn a doctorate and to be known as a "doctor" of the field. Only "novelty" will do.

Comment: The notion of _scholarship_ is really enlightening. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

A PhD thesis demonstrates the candidate's ability to perform research. Research, by definition, adds something novel to the body of knowledge.

> *Research:* The systematic investigation into and study of materials  and sources
>   in order to establish facts and reach new conclusions
>   ([Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/research))

Answer (score 9):

## Axiom

My answer derive from following definition of the PhD and its thesis.

> The **purpose of a PhD** is to train a research student as an **autonomous scientist**
>   and a **good researcher** — i.e., as someone deserving the grade of Doctor.
>
> The **objective of a PhD thesis** is hence to **demonstrate to one’s peers** that its author can be considered in this way by **reporting the successful* completion of a high-quality piece of research**.

Depending on one's field, the monograph-style thesis can be replaced by a set of published peer-reviewed paper. The objective remains the same.

## Question

The question is then ***"What is an autonomous scientist and a good researcher?"***

> Being a good researcher means first to **do science well**, second to **do good
>   science**, and third to **do a lot of science**.
>
> *Doing science well* means following its **ethical rules**, being **thorough**, **honestly** and appropriately **reporting one’s results**, **crediting one’s peers** for their work and **acknowledging** one’s work **limitations**, using the **adequate tools and methods** to solve a problem, and doing research that is **reproducible**.
>
> *Doing good science* means addressing a **relevant scientific gap**, an issue that is influential, a research problem that matters for science, the society, and the industry.
>
> *Doing a lot of science* means to tackle a large-scale problem, to **address subsequent research gaps**, to contribute to multiple issues of a coherent sub-field.
>
> One must, however, note that **these criteria are conditional to one another**. Doing a lot of science serves no purpose if one does not do good science. And more importantly, doing good science serves no purpose if one does not do science well.

To this, I would add that (it is my opinion, and one may disagree) **the job of a researcher is to do science**.
And **doing science means reporting new knowledge that is as truthful as possible**.
This is achievable using the **scientific method** that is commonly acknowledged as the best method for creating/unveiling (depending on your ontological positioning) reliable new knowledge.

## Answer

So, to pragmatically answer your question:

- **the purpose a a PhD is to train you as a scientist**,
- **producing new** (and highly reliable) **knowledge is quintessentially the role of a scientist**.

Hence, ***you cannot be recognized by your peers as a scientist*** *(i.e., being awarded the _Doctor_ title)* ***if you don't prove that you can produce new reliable knowledge by yourself***.

The confusion might come from the fact that — as it has been highlighted in comments — scientists do literature review, and literature review are useful and valuable. However, they are not the core of what *is* a scientist.

## Post-scriptum

It it worth highlighting again the last quoted paragraph:

> **These criteria are conditional to one another**. Doing a lot of science serves no purpose if one does not do good science. And more importantly, doing good science serves no purpose if one does not do science well.

Thus, I think that, **when doing a PhD**, one should mainly **focus of the quality of one's contribution, rather than breadth or scale.**

In other words: what matters is not that much *what* you have proven, but *how* you have proven it.

Of course I had the dream of a breakthrough thesis.
Yet I think that, during a PhD, it is more important to produce only a few robust, well designed experiment and well reported results on a minor "research gap"; rather than aiming to tackle a large scale issue without being able to produce robust results or reliable conclusions.

It's only once you'll have proven that you are a good researcher and autonomous scientist, that you'll be able to secure a job as a scientist/researcher.

And **then you'll have time** (and money, and support, and experience, …) **to shoot for the stars**.
Yet **this is not the objective of a PhD**. Everything in its own time.

---

<sub>Citations are excerpt of… the preface of my PhD thesis.</sub>

<sub>* Note that *"successful"* is to be understood as *"We have completed each step of the scientific method"*. I.e., it does not consider whether results are positive or negative.</sub>

Comment: This answer has some excellent points — e.g. the core answer that a PhD thesis must demonstrate the candidate’s capability as a scientist, and that’s why it needs novelty — mixed in with some very tendentious and field-dependent claims, like the idea *‘“successful” is to be understood as “We have been able to demonstrate with certainty that” rather than “there is a correlation/impact/link between A and B”.’* — there are whole fields of science where this is a complete category error as to the nature of research.  It would benefit from focusing more on the uncontroversial key points.

Comment: @PLL PS: Out of curiosity/interest, could you please elaborate on your point ("there are whole fields of science where this is a complete category error as to the nature of research.") — e.g., with some examples?

Comment: Also interestingly enough is doesn't provide insight to the behind the scenes workings of the publication and review process which are machines which need much maintenance akin to the legal systems in some sense of the terms.

Comment: "...you cannot be recognized by your peers as a scientist if you don't prove that you can produce new reliable knowledge by yourself." That might be an example of jumping to conclusions. I could recognize someone as a scientist even without that proof, for example by having enough trust that anyone could be a scientist in principle.